# Eclipse + Tomcat + Maven gives class not found exception even after adding Maven Libraries

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tomcat

I have a project which I add on the Tomcat 8 server to debug, as there is something in the doPost method that is not working as I want.
When I try to launch the server, everything goes fine, but as soon as I do a GET, the server crashes and give a class not found exception.
Putting the war inside the tomcat folder it works fine and what is even more strange is that the GET works with the old URL, giving the answer I wrote at the beginning of my study.
I have tried to follow some of the answer, but had no luck. Please Help!

EDIT: My application is a simple doGet doPost servlet and the error I get is

```
Jun 22, 2016 5:21:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet controlServlet
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: gft.serverReceiver.ServletProducer
    at    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1332)
    at     org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1166)
etcetera ect...
```

This happens when I do a get on the address `http://localhost:8080/deviceReceiver/producer`, which is the address I declared in the `web.xml` file.
If I try to use the default eclipse address: `http://localhost:8080/deviceReceiver`, I get a response that I coded the first time, something on the like of "Hello World!"

Comment: Please provide more information about your application and the error you encountered.

Comment: @MickaëlB I did, sorry for before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have solved this was re-installing Eclipse and doing the [Install Tomcat on Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/jst/components/ws/1.5/tutorials/InstallTomcat/InstallTomcat.html) procedure all over again.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please ensure that the class `ServletProducer` is in the package `gft.serverReceiver` ?

Like :

```
package gft.serverReceiver;

public class ServletProducer {
  // ...
}
```

Also, please ensure that in your `web.xml`, you have something like :

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>ServletProducer</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>gft.serverReceiver.ServletProducer</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>ServletProducer</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: I have. The application works when I use it on Tomcat, putting it in the webapps folder.